# Use XMLHttpRequest and Get to pass Javascript variabels to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I want to fetch the window width/window.innerWidth/CONSTANT1, from Javascript to PHP:

HTML:

```
<p>Resize the browser window to fire the <code>resize</code> event.</p>
<p>Window height: <span id="height"></span></p>
<p>Window width: <span id="width"></span></p>
```

Javascript (the working part as seen by the working alert):

```
const heightOutput = document.querySelector("#height");
const widthOutput = document.querySelector("#width");
var $CONSTANT1 = window.innerWidth;
var $CONSTANT2 = window.innerHeight;

function updateSize() {
  heightOutput.textContent = window.innerHeight;
  widthOutput.textContent = window.innerWidth;
}

updateSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
alert('Width='+$CONSTANT1+'px' + ', Hight=' + $CONSTANT2+'px'); //This alert works
```

Javascript (the non-working part):

```
    function test() {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            xxx = (ajax.responseText);
            console.log(xxx);

          }
        };
        ajax.open("GET", 'footer.php?CONSTANT1='+CONSTANT1, true);
        ajax.send(null);

    }
```

I want to fetch the width, CONSTANT1, from Javascript to the PHP vairable $CONSTANT1.

PHP:

```
$CONSTANT1= $_GET['CONSTANT1'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$CONSTANT1.'");</script>';
```

I do not really understand what

```
ajax.open("GET", 'footer.php?CONSTANT1='+CONSTANT1, true);
```

has for function, but all the Javascript code and PHP code is in the footer.php.
I tried with the full URL but did not work either.

Here is a codepen for the working Javascript code:
https://codepen.io/G1111/pen/vYQyqMe

Comment: Simply doing an ajax request does not load html from the endpoint into the document, so your javascript code you are retrieving from your php script doesnt run

Comment: Could you elaborate what you're trying to accomplish? At the moment it looks like you want to send a value to PHP from JS, and then send the value back?

Comment: I want to send a value to PHP from JS. I do not want to send anything back. I want to get  $CONSTANT1= $_GET['CONSTANT1']; to PHP for further processing in PHP.

Comment: I just took a syntax for XMLHttpRequest that I found on the internet...the code is wrong but that is the closest that I could come.

Comment: It's a bit unclear *what* specifically doesn't work. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Ultimately, i want the PHP code to alert the variable $CONSTANT1, by using echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$CONSTANT1.'");</script>';. But right now the alerted message is empty which means that the variable  $CONSTANT1 is never passed to PHP. I tried to look at many examples of XMLHttpRequest online but everyone is so different that I could not see any consensus.

Comment: I think there are multiple problems here, the first one is a simple typo.  Your JS variable includes a $ - `var $CONSTANT1 = ...`.  But you are not using that variable in your AJAX request: `ajax.open("GET", 'footer.php?CONSTANT1='+CONSTANT1, true);`.  Next problem is that variable seems to be only set once, on page load.  You need to update it in `updateSize()`, so it is live and up-to-date, surely?  Lastly, running some JS which fires an AJAX request to PHP to return some JS you want to then execute is ... a bit strange!? :-) There are better ways to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need :

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://URL_OF_YOUR_BACKEND';
var params = `CONSTANT1=${value1}&CONSTANT2=${value2}`; // Add parameters here

xhr.open('GET', url + '?' + params, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
xhr.responseType = 'text';

xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var responseData = xhr.response;
    alert(responseData);
  } else {
    console.error('Request failed. Status:', xhr.status);
  }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.error('Request failed due to a network error');
};

xhr.send();
```

If you insist on returning js response from server , which is not what I recommend , you can use :

```
// Use eval() to execute the JavaScript code
    eval(responseText);
```

---

If I were you, on the other hand, I would use Fetch API like following to be more concise and follow modern js patterns:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('CONSTANT1', $CONSTANT1);
params.append('CONSTANT2', $CONSTANT2);

const url = new URL('https://URL_TO_BACKEND');
url.search = params.toString();

fetch(url.toString(), {
  method: 'GET',  
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Request failed with status: ' + response.status);
    }
}).then(payload => {
  alert(payload.data);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Request failed due to a network error:', error);
});
```

And for server side :

```
<?php
$CONSTANT1= $_GET['CONSTANT1'];

// Handle the request and prepare the response
$response = array(
  'data' => $CONSTANT1
);

// Convert the response to JSON format
$responseJson = json_encode($response);

// Set the appropriate headers for the response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // Allow cross-origin requests (adjust as needed)

// Send the JSON response
echo $responseJson;
?>
```

FYI, there are a lot of code combinations to achieve what you want :D